# Save the data even if their value in a form is null?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

If I not complete the form for "annoinizio" or "annofine" or "stagioni" or "totepisodi" django plays form.is_valid() and returns False. How can I save the data even if their value is null?

Models:

```
class Tvserie(models.Model):
        titolo = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
        titolo_originale = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
```

Views:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
        titolo = forms.CharField(required=False)
        titolo_originale = forms.CharField(required=False)

def  nuovaserie(request):
       if request.method == 'POST':
         form=ContactForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
           titolo = request.POST.get('titolo','')
           titolo_originale = request.POST.get('titolo_originale','')

           cont_obj= Tvserie.objects.create(titolo = titolo, titolo_originale = titolo_originale)
           cont_obj.save()

           return HttpResponseRedirect('/risultatonuovaserie/')
       else:
         form=ContactForm()
         return render(request , 'NuovaSerie.html', {'form': form})
```

Templates:

```
<form action="/nuovaserie/" method="POST">
  <table border=1>
    <tr>
      <td><label>Titolo*:</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="titolo" value="{{titolo}}"></td>
      <td><label>Titolo originale*:</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="titolo_originale" value="{{titolo_originale}}"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>                                
      <td colspan="4"><center><input type="submit" value="Invia"></center></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 </form>
```

Comment: You don't have any of those fields in your form or template.

Comment: 1. Don't define your form on views.py
2. After form.is_valid() use the form's cleaned data, not the straight request
3. Can you append the stack trace? i don't see the fields you mention anywhere, so it may be some issue at model level instead than at forms.

Answer (score 0):

In models.py:

```
class Tvserie(models.Model):
    titolo = models.CharField(max_length = 100,blank=True,null=True)
    titolo_originale = models.CharField(max_length = 200,blank=True,null=True)
```

In forms.py

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    titolo = forms.CharField(required=False)
    titolo_originale = forms.CharField(required=False)
```